# C read() : Invalid arguments

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to read from a nbd device with function `read()`

Here is the code:

```
static uint64_t hash_log_free_list;
int fd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE);
assert(fd != -1);
int err = read(fd, &hash_log_free_list, sizeof(uint64_t));
if (err != sizeof(uint64_t))
{
    MSGDEBUG

    perror("read");
    printf("err: %d\n", err);
    abort();
}
```

argv[2] is a nbd device: /dev/nbd0

**MSGDEBUG** is defined to print __FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__

and I got the error msg:

> Error!!!  dedup.c: 554: main  read: Invalid argument err: 0
>   Aborted

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check if `fd == -1` after `open`. If yes, the file could not be opened.

Comment: You should check, if err is really `-1` or if it returned some other value. In the latter case, the errno EINVAL might be related to an earlier function call

Comment: You checked the read() return, but not the preceeding open() :((

Comment: @MichaelWalz in that case, EBADF would be expected from read()

Comment: @Ctx yes, but he should check anyway,

Comment: I checked that `fd != -1` and `err == 0` @MichaelWalz @Ctx @ThingyWotsit

Comment: It is not an error for `read` to read less bytes than requested. You should check the return value for 0 (end of file) and <0 (an error).

Comment: The `errno` value is irrelevant - a return value of `0` from `read()` is not an error, so the `read()` call did not change the previous value of `errno`.

Comment: @Ctx *in that case, EBADF would be expected from read()* I'n not so sure about that.  The [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)'s "**EINVAL** `fd` is attached to an object which is unsuitable for reading" seems to contradict [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html):  "**EBADF** The `fildes` argument is not a valid file descriptor open for reading."

Comment: Ugh, don't use macros to make things that act like functions but don't look like them. Something like  `#define MSGDEBUG() printf(...)` used as  `MSGDEBUG();` would be much prettier.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You even cite it: `EINVAL`: fd is _attached_ to an object  which is unsuitable for reading. Thus, this errno would not be applicable, if the fd isn't in use at all. `EBADF`is for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` returns 0 which is not an error, it just tells you that there's nothing to read.

You can use `select`/`epoll` before calling `read` to make sure there's actual data to read.

Also, remove the `MSGDEBUG` line because it's printing stuff and most probably changing `errno` at the same time, so your `perror` probably gives you information about what happend in `MSGDEBUG`, not in the `read` before it.

Comment: No, if the file descriptor is non-blocking, it will return `-EAGAIN` if there is nothing to read. 0 only occurs on EOF

Comment: also, `errno` is only changed if and when an error happens. If neither the debug output, or the `read()` itself return an error, then the error code left in `errno` will be from something earlier, and probably not very relevant.

Comment: @ilkkachu nope, errno doesn't need an error to be updated, it's also changed on success (set to 0).

Comment: @yoones, well, probably not. The [man page errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) states: _"[errno] is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an error to indicate what went wrong.  Its value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error"_, and _"errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function."_. It does also say that a _"function that succeeds **is** allowed to change errno."_, but I'm not sure if that means it's only allowed to change to some other error.

Comment: @yoones, empirically, I wouldn't count on it being set to zero by a successful call, try something like `errno = 1234; int a = write(1, "foo\n", 4); printf("retval: %d errno now: %d\n", a, errno);`

Comment: @ilkkachu you're right, but the notes section in the manpage errno(3) states that *If the value of errno should be preserved across a library call, it must be saved*. I'm not saying one should expect errno to be 0 on success, I'm saying one must acknowledge that errno *could* change and be set to 0, thus the need for a pessimistic approach when error-checking.

Comment: @yoones, yeah, it could change, but not to zero.